# Is it possible to get the cgroup path for a Docker container managed by Kubernetes?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cgroup

When we use `kubectl describe pods <pod_name>`, a great deal of information is output, including the node that the server is running on, and miscellaneous information about the pod, including the container IDs and images.

If we ssh into the node, we can poke around `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/kubepods` and find directories such as `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/kubepods/pod6cbf8d09-2a76-11e9-9f3e-42010a80003b`, which have subdirectories that look like hashes. If we examine the processes listed in the `cgroup.procs` pseudofile inside these subdirectories, we can infer that these subdirectories correspond to the Docker containers started by Kubernetes.

Unfortunately, a human must manually examine the `cgroup.procs` file to infer which container each directory corresponds to.

**Is there a way to get names of the subdirectory path under `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/kubepods` which corresponds to a specific container inside a pod?**

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest renaming the container subdirectories as the containers within them hashes. If you rename these subdirectories, it could in fact break the file-system.

Also, /sys holds information and configurations that the kernel provides. Changing any information or configurations within this directory can lead to unintended behavior within the node.